# Check what has been done in a given time period

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

Is it possible to check what a server administrator has actually done during routine maintenance by viewing event logs etc?

I'm trying to establish what the administrator is actually doing as I don't see any changes to the system in terms of alerts being cleared or updates being applied to the server etc.

I'd like to be able to see exactly what was done during the hours that are billed for.

Comment: Any particular reason for all the down votes? I'd like to know why so I can edit the question and avoid the same mistake again... Apologies for my apparent ignorance!

Comment: Imagine going into a police office's break room and asking how to spy on their colleaugues. And you have a pretty good comparison for the downvotes here.

Comment: @reaces Fair enough, my bad! Honestly it was more about finding a reason not to flag an issue than the other way around. I'm not out of pocket in this situation but was trying to do the right thing. I'm sorry if I offended anyone...

Answer (score 2):

Ask your server administrator directly...

Depending on your server and your applications there are several logs that could possibly contain bits of information as to what a person was doing.
If you have a SQL server, he might have ran indexing jobs.
If you have a Vsphere environment he might have updated some of the templates or looked at the resource and redistributed them.
He might have simply reviewed logs, created a history of events for baseline purposes.

These are all things you'd need to check separately, as the list of possible activities rises, so does the amount of places you need to check.

And this is all assuming the logs still exist, and you know where to find them.
If you don't trust your administrators, look for new administrators.
They have full control of your system, and if there is any animosity and you don't trust their characters, then you have bigger problems than wasted billing time.

Comment: +1 purely for "if you don't trust them, you have bigger problems than billing".

Comment: Thank you for the sound advice, and normally you'd be right about asking them directly. Unfortunately I'm not in a position to talk with them as it is not my place. And in fairness to the admin I don't want to bring it to the attention of the people who are in that position without having at least some kind of evidence that they are not doing their job properly... It may purely be my own ignorance that is leading me to have concerns hence the reason for asking the question.